# How can I prevent the MLB At Bat app from going into "Offline Mode"?

Tags: iphone, ios

Frequently (sometimes several times a day) I see the following when I launch the [MLB At Bat](https://itunes.apple.com/app/mlb-at-bat/id493619333) app on my iPhone X, running iOS 11.4.1:

[image]

The app then refuses to let me use certain functionality (like "Gameday"), because it's now in this mode.

The only way to get the app working again is to force it to close and relaunch.

I sent a support email to MLB.com Mobile Customer Support and got steps on how to update to the most current release. (which it already is.) The reply closes with "If you have any additional questions, please contact Apple for further assistance."

How can I troubleshoot or prevent this from happening?

Comment: It's their app so most likely their problem. I would contact support again.

Comment: Interesting. I use that app a lot and it has never entered that mode.  But I have an iphone 6.  Are you running ios 11.4.1?

Comment: Yes, 11.4.1. I updated the question.

Comment: @DarylSpitzer Did you try reinstalling the app?

Comment: No, I guess I should try reinstalling. Even though I don't understand how that could fix it, at least I could say if it didn't.